# Integral of $e^xf(x)$ by knowing the integral of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f(x):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and set $\int_a^b f(x)dx=c$. Is it possible to express $\int_a^b e^x f(x)dx$ as a function of $c$?

My intuition is that a closed form expression does not exist. However, I was wondering whether some series expansions could be found.

Comment: You have $e^a c \leq \int_a^be^xf(x)\mathrm{d}x \leq e^b c$, but apart from that, I don't think we could add much more. We would really need to know how $f$ behaves on $[a,b]$ precisely to see how multiplying by $e^x$ would affect it. Having $c$ is probably not enough.

Comment: For instance, on $[a,b] = [0,1]$, and $f(x) = 1$, $g(x) = 2x$, you have $\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm{d}x=  \int_0^1g(x)\mathrm{d}x =1 = c$ but probably $\int_0^1e^xf(x)\mathrm{d}x \ne \int_0^1e^xg(x)\mathrm{d}x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to express your integral as a function of $c$.

Just insert any two functions that integrate to c=1 and you'll almost surely have a counterexample.